# mysql search query issue like query

Tags: mysql

[image]

My column value like this.
I want to search the value 1 from the given column.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_test` WHERE `userServices` LIKE '%1%' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But the above query gives me two values row 2 and 3

Comment: %LIKE% sentence search all posibilities for 1, like 1,2 or 11. If you want just 1 use **=**, userServices = 1

Comment: But my column values are like this 1,2 in each row. And = , LIKE,IN not working

Comment: I can't understand what you need. All values that start with 1?, give examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FIND_IN_SET`.

The below query should work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_test` WHERE find_in_set('1', `userServices`) <> 0;
```